# Run ML pipeline using AWS step function for entire dataset?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

I have a step function setup which calls preprocessing lambda and inference lambda for a data item. Now, I need to do this process on the entire dataset(over 10000 items). One way is to invoke step function parallelly for each input. Is there a better alternative to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to use Map state to run over an array of items. You could start with a list of item ID's and run a set of tasks for it.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-step-functions-support-for-dynamic-parallelism/

This approach has some drawbacks though:

1. There is a 256kb limit for input/output data. The initial array of items could possibly be bigger. If you passes an array of ID's only as an input to map state though, 10k items would likely not cross that limit.
2. Map state doesn't guarantee that all the items will run concurrently. It could possibly be less than 40 at a time (workaround would be to have nested map states or maps of map states). From documentation:

> Concurrent iterations may be limited. When this occurs, some iterations will not begin until previous iterations have completed. The likelihood of this occurring increases when your input array has more than 40 items.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html